# curl command - could not resolve xn--x-5gn/post on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, curl

I am using curl command to call rest api. I want to post data and my curl command looks like:

```
curl –x POST -u 'username:PW' -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"json-input":{"handler":"getContent","image":true,"video":false,"text":false,"source":"1","lage":"testlage1"}}' -i  http://localhost:8080/com.knime.enterprise.server/rest/v4/jobs/3fd2ca61-c173-4160-a20d-45c387f65f64
```

I am getting following message:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn--x-5gn curl: (6) Could not
>   resolve host: POST

Comment: Try this command : curl --request POST -u 'username:PW' -k -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"json-input":{"handler":"getContent","image":true,"video":false,"text":false,"source":"1","lage":"testlage1"}}' -i  http://localhost:8080/com.knime.enterprise.server/rest/v4/jobs/3fd2ca61-c173-4160-a20d-45c387f65f64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The letter before `X` is wrong. It is supposed to be an ascii minus ('-', ascii code 0x2d / 45) and not the [unicode dash character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (U+2013) as used in the question.

curl will treat all options that don't start with a minus as a URL, which makes it convert the dash-X string to a IDN hostname and try it. It then continues to try the "POST" host name as that follows the dash-X... None of those host names can be resolved, which is the curl error messages you see.

Then finally: don't use `-X POST` when you do a post with `-d` (or with `-F`)! Just remove the `-X POST` entirely and things will work better.

Comment: curl: no URL specified!
Now my code looks like this now: let getDataUrl = "http://localhost:8080/com.knime.enterprise.server/rest/v4/jobs/"        let dataStringFy = {"json-input":{"handler":"getContent","image":true,"video":false,"text":false,"source":"1","lage":"testlage1"}}                                                                                                     let cmd = "curl -X POST -u 'username:pw -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d" +"'"+ dataStringyFy + "'"  + getDataUrl ;

Comment: So instead of following my advice you instead butchered the command line completely? I'm not sure that's a way forward here...

Answer (score 1):

check the codepage settings of the terminal software in use and compare these to the host settings

in our case we saw the same strange hostname error returned to a simple

curl -v http://{hostname}:{port}

we discovered the problem was the dash character; the codepage specified in Putty was not consistent with the codepage used at the host so curl treated the -v expression as the hostname.